# jQuery Dropdown Mouseout only when outside of the div

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, mouseover, mouseout

**Problem**

The MouseOut should only go out when the user goes outside the DIV. So they can hover over the links etc. It just stays expanding it does not go back

**JS Fiddle and DEMO** ([http://jsfiddle.net/GHaL7/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/GHaL7/1/))

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hoverButton").mouseover(function () {
        $('div.hoverMenu').slideDown(2000)
    });
    $("div.hoverMenu").mouseout(function () {
        $('div.hoverMenu').slideUp(2000)
    }); 
});
```

**CSS/HTML**

```
<style type="text/css">
.grooveKhaleelMenu{position:relative;z-index:10000}
.hoverMenu{display:none;width:233px;height:350px;position:absolute;top:26px}
div.hoverMenu ul li{margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px}
div.hoverMenu ul li a span{font-size:16px !important}
.nav_zone{float:left;height:24px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;z-index:10000}
.nav_menu li{float:left;margin-right:1px;overflow:hidden;width:233px;height:24px;display:block}
.nav_menu a{display:block;margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:2px;text-decoration:none;font-size:18px}
.newshop{position:relative;z-index:700}
.grooveKhaleelMenu li, .grooveKhaleelMenu li a{color:#fff;text-align:center}
.blackLink{background:#000}
.blackLink:hover{background:#525252}
.redLink{background:#d40f20}
.redLink:hover{background:#e82e22}
</style>




<div class="shoulders topofthedress">
    <div class="nav_zone">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_menu grooveKhaleelMenu">
                <li class="blackLink" id="hoverButton"><a href="/shop" title="Shop all"><span>SHOP</span></a></li>
                <div class="hoverMenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Cat</span></a></li>
                                <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Cat</span></a></li>
                                <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Cat</span></a></li>
                                <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Cat</span></a></li>
                                <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Cat</span></a></li>
                                <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Cat</span></a></li>
                        <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Cat</span></a></li>
                        <li class="redLink"><a href="/shop/cat/sub" title="Sub Cat"><span>Sub Sale Cat</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat"><span>Shop Cat</span></a></li>
                <li class="blackLink"><a href="/shop/cat"><span>Shop Cat</span></a></li>
                <li class="redLink"><a href="/shop/cat"><span>Sale Cat</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First you have two slideUp, but that will not work because there is a margin-top and margin-bottom to seperate those sub menus so it all does not look black.. I get what you are trying but I cant figure it

Comment: @TheBlackBenzkid check to this http://jsfiddle.net/GHaL7/3/

Comment: It does not work @RohitAzad Thanks for the post - it slides up before you can even click SUB CAT..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you dont use slideUp() in your script?

possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GHaL7/23/

Comment: I think because he has a margin gap between the sub menus, so even if you move your mouse between those sub menus it still will slideup still does not stay fixed.

Comment: Can you show me the JSFiddle - also please do not delete your answer. Other people just post and delete because they cant solve.

Comment: or try to add it to the hovered li element, cause it will function as wrapper;-)

Comment: can you please show me the sample? I am up http://jsfiddle.net/GHaL7/21/ different 21 tries! And no luck!